Hilbert spaces that include algebraic polynomials
This question is motivated by a phrase I found in several books/papers about approximation theory, for example, M.J.D.Powell's Approximation Theory and Methods: ''Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space that contains the subspace $\Pi^n$  of algebraic polynomials of degree $n$."  (misprint, meaning ''at most $n$''). How many of such spaces can we find?  Let's state the question formally, in several variables.
Let $\Pi^n$ be the space of algebraic polynomials in $d$ variables up to degree $n$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a ball (or an open set, not relevant info), and let  $(\mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle)$  be a Hilbert space of real valued functions defined on $B$ such that  $\Pi^d \subseteq \mathcal{H}$  (briefly, a Hilbert space of real valued functions that contains at least the polynomials up to degree $n$). For example, Lebesgue spaces $L^2(B,\mu)$ ($\mu$ a Borel measure), or Sobolev spaces $H^k(B)$.  Note that in both of these spaces, the inner product is related to the Lebesgue integral (with an appropriate measure and/or appropriate functions).
The following two questions arise:

Besides the Lebesgue and the Sobolev, are there any other (nontrivial/interesting) examples of Hilbert spaces that contain at least the polynomials up to degree $n$?
Are there inner products (in such spaces) non-related to Lebesgue integral?

My initial thought was in the following way: as the constants are in $\mathcal{H}$, you get that the functional $f \rightarrow \langle f,1 \rangle$ is continuous, suggesting that the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani  representation theorem might be used (in case the space contains the continuous functions), and so the answer to question 2 may be NO...or maybe this can lead to a way to find a counterexample.

This question, with a slight modification, was originally posted on StackExchange/Math.

$\Pi^n$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Any choice of basis induces exactly one inner product that makes it orthonormal.
